# MongoDB vs Python timestamp resolution

Tags: python, mongodb, timestamp

I have just noticed that MongoDB Python driver (or the DB itself?) is incapable of storing DateTime object with the sort of resolution that Python allows:

```
ts = datetime.datetime.now()
print(ts) # datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 3, 20, 12, 8, 179786)
db.test.insert({'ts': ts})
cursor = db.test.find()
for result in cursor:
    from_db = result
print(from_db['ts']) # datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 3, 20, 12, 8, 179000)
```

Is this the expected behaviour or a bug?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is a known behaviour:
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON-1173